# laravel 5 scheduler cronjob output to mail

Tags: laravel-5

Laravel 5 has the ability to send output of scheduled commands to e-mail.

But that isn't working; what is wrong about?

```
$schedule->command('foo:bar')
         ->twiceDaily()
         ->sendOutputTo(storage_path().'/logs/cron.log')
         ->emailOutputTo('backup@mail.biz');
```

The output IS saved to the cron.log file, but not in my mailbox - not even the spam-folder.

I configured e-mail by using "mailgun" as a service in the mail-config. Normal e-mailing works.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors showing up in the Larvel error log?  I'm getting exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal offset type' in vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMessage.php:297.  I haven't yet taken the time to figure out what the cause is.

Comment: @orrd, made an issue already: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7639